# Loading progress bar for all the download tasks

Tags: codenameone

I know that theres a NetworkManager class in Codename One that does the HTTP requests.
Im not quite sure as to where to have all of those download requests queued in a thread and have a loading progress percentage to track the overall downloaded percentage?
Is there a way to do that? I would like to download some images on different URL paths and need to prompt a progress bar to my user to have a different progress bars for each images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkManager.getInstance().addProgressListener()` will send an action event that you can downcast to a `NetworkEvent`. From that event you can extract the exact status/progress of the current connection.

You can use the `SliderBridge` to bind a `Slider` as a network activity progress indicator. You can also [study its code](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/SliderBridge.java) to write something similar on your own.